# How do I sort column by targeting a specific number within that cell?

Tags: pandas

I would like to use Pandas Python to sort a specific column by date (more specifically the year). However, the year is buried within a bunch of other numbers. How do I just target the 2 digits that I need?

In the example below, I want to sort this column by the numbers [16,14,15...] rather than considering all the numbers in that row.

```
3/18/16 11:46
6/19/14 14:58
7/27/15 14:22
8/3/15 12:59
2/20/13 12:33
9/27/16 12:08
7/27/15 14:22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a dataframe like this,

```
    date
0   3/18/16
1   6/19/14
2   7/27/15
3   8/3/15
4   2/20/13
5   9/27/16
6   7/27/15
```

You can convert the date column to datetime format and then sort.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values(by = 'date')
```

The resulting dataframe

```
    date
4   2013-02-20
1   2014-06-19
2   2015-07-27
6   2015-07-27
3   2015-08-03
0   2016-03-18
5   2016-09-27
```

Comment: Thanks. If you don't mind me asking, how could I separate the time and date into diff columns then I can sort the time separately?

Comment: You don't have to separate date and time. to_datetime will work perfectly well on it together